# How to order by Strings with german umlauts in JPQL?

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

Using java code, it is possible to sort german umlauts correctly with something like this:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
    Comparator umlautCollator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return umlautCollator.compare(o1, o2);
    }
});
```

I'd like to do such an order in my JPQL statement, without using a subsequent `sort`. Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean - the default "order by" JPQL statement? Yes, it fails, all umlauts are at the end of the result list.

Comment: Did you consider removing diacritics from German letters and sorting it using default sort? Or this is not a solution?

Comment: @edze It's a Oracle 10g.

Comment: @JMelnik This is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that your database supports Unicode collation for the character set that you are using, e.g. UTF-8. Java ddes Unicode by default which is why the comparator class works.

Presumably your database doesn't - you're probably using US-ASCII, right?

Recreate your database and convert your data is the hard answer.

Comment: I'm using Oracle 10g. Is it a database setting or can it be set per table?

Comment: You can even do it at the column level. But it won't help you if you not in charge of your database. You have a DBA right? Otherwise I don't think you would have asked that question. If you are the DBA yourself, then great - even better if you don't have thousands of rows of data to convert.